# Linkedin Salesforce integration

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate salesforce and Linkedin. Use case is if we send any data it should be send to linked in from salesforce. and any updates have to be displayed in salesforce . I have tried with some extensions linke Ebsta but it is used to insert record as lead or contact or account from browser extension. Kindly suggest how we cna acive it posting data into linked in from salesforce and vice versa.

Thanks.

Comment: see https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/integrating-salesforce-and-linkedin; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658343/getting-basic-profile-info-through-linkedin-api-from-salesforce; and https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/06/integrating-linkedin-with-forcecom.html (latter written by SFDC Developer Evangelist)

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you will have to do some reading on the LinkedIn REST API.

[Check out the API here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.